# SSRS-range bar chart axis label in quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, axis-labels

I've created a **range bar chart** using SSRS 2008.

It is a **date** range

**StartDate** is `=DateAdd("yyyy",-2,Today())`

**EndDate** is `=DateAdd("yyyy",2,Today())`

Is there a way to format the Axis labels to show in Quarters?? 
I am able to display in **"MMM-YY"** format. But I want it in **"Qq-yyyy"** format.

Thanks!! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use following format:

```
="Q"+Cstr(DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today()))+" - "+Cstr(Format(Today(),"yyyy"))
```

Output will be : `"Q4 - 2014"`

Put Your Date Field/Axis labels Filed instead of "Today()" in above expression.

Comment: I'm getting `Q4-2014` for all the intervals.

Comment: which field is in your Axis labels ??

Comment: Its a range bar chart having range between **StartDate** and **EndDate**. Doesn't take range from a field. Those date values is selected by user in parameters.

Comment: I have the date... which is displayed in **"MMM-yy"** format

Comment: so put the above expression on that Axis Label `="Q"+Cstr(DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,<yourDateField>))+" - "+Cstr(Format(<yourDateField>,"yyyy"))`

Comment: The problem is I don't have a date field. Its is the range that is date.